# Archery example of Zeno's Paradox in Python

Tags: python

So here's what I have to simulate [Zeno's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes#Dichotomy_paradox):

```
def zenos_paradox(archer_position, target_position, steps):
    current = archer_position
    print("The arrow is released at position ", archer_position)
    print("It is aimed at postion ", target_position)
    for step in range(steps):
        current = current + (target_position / 2) #change this to be 
        print("Position of the arrow at step ", step+1, "is ", current)
    return(current)

def question_2():
    answer = zenos_paradox(0,100,5)
    print("The answer is: ", answer)

question_2()
```

Here's my printout:

```
The arrow is released at position  0
It is aimed at postion  100
Position of the arrow at step  1 is  50.0
Position of the arrow at step  2 is  100.0
Position of the arrow at step  3 is  150.0
Position of the arrow at step  4 is  200.0
Position of the arrow at step  5 is  250.0
The answer is:  250.0
```

My desired printout:

```
The arrow is released at position 0
It is aimed at position 100
Position of the arrow at step 1 is 50.0
Position of the arrow at step 2 is 75.0
Position of the arrow at step 3 is 87.5
Position of the arrow at step 4 is 93.75
Position of the arrow at step 5 is 96.875
The answer is:  96.875
```

I know that the position has to increase each step by the distance of the previous increase divided by 2. So the first jump in distance is 50m, then 25, then 12.5, then 6.25. I believe I should be adding a line somewhere, but I can't figure out how to work that into the code.

Comment: I believe the math should be `current = current + ((target_position - current) / 2)`

Comment: You need `2**(step+1)` instead of 2 in the denominator, check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`current + (target_position / 2)` makes no sense, as you're adding half the distance between the target position and the starting point every step, when you want to be adding half the distance between the target position and the **current** position. So, it'd be `current = current + (target_position - current) / 2`, which can be simplified with math into just taking the average: `current = (current + target_position) / 2`:

```py
def zenos_paradox(archer_position, target_position, steps):
    current = archer_position
    print("The arrow is released at position ", archer_position)
    print("It is aimed at postion ", target_position)
    for step in range(steps):
        current = (current + target_position) / 2
        print("Position of the arrow at step ", step+1, "is ", current)
    return(current)

def question_2():
    answer = zenos_paradox(0,100,5)
    print("The answer is: ", answer)

question_2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should save the new value of `target_position` after you divide it by two. So instead of

```py
current = current + (target_position / 2)
```

Try this:

```py
target_position /= 2
current = current + target_position
```

Full code:

```py
def zenos_paradox(archer_position, target_position, steps):
    current = archer_position
    print("The arrow is released at position ", archer_position)
    print("It is aimed at postion ", target_position)
    for step in range(steps):
        target_position /= 2
        current = current + target_position #change this to be 
        print("Position of the arrow at step ", step+1, "is ", current)
    return(current)

def question_2():
    answer = zenos_paradox(0,100,5)
    print("The answer is: ", answer)

question_2()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the current position from the target position, and divide that by 2, not the target position itself.

```
def zenos_paradox(archer_position, target_position, steps):
    current = archer_position
    print("The arrow is released at position ", archer_position)
    print("It is aimed at postion ", target_position)
    for step in range(steps):
        current = current + (target_position - current) / 2
        print("Position of the arrow at step ", step+1, "is ", current)
    return(current)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `2^n` instead to the denominator since the division has to be exponentially incremented -

```
def zenos_paradox(archer_position, target_position, steps):
    current = archer_position
    print("The arrow is released at position ", archer_position)
    print("It is aimed at postion ", target_position)
    for step in range(steps):
        current = current + (target_position / 2**(step+1)) #change this to be 
        print("Position of the arrow at step ", step+1, "is ", current)
    return(current)

def question_2():
    answer = zenos_paradox(0,100,5)
    print("The answer is: ", answer)

question_2()
```

```
The arrow is released at position  0
It is aimed at postion  100
Position of the arrow at step  1 is  50.0
Position of the arrow at step  2 is  75.0
Position of the arrow at step  3 is  87.5
Position of the arrow at step  4 is  93.75
Position of the arrow at step  5 is  96.875
The answer is:  96.875
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun: `numpy` could get you there as well:

```
import numpy as np

def zenos_paradox(start,stop,steps):
    print("The arrow is released at position ", start)
    print("It is aimed at postion ", stop)
    paradox = start + (1-np.ones(steps+1)*0.5**np.arange(steps+1)) * (stop-start)
    [print("Position of the arrow at step {} is {}".format(s,p)) for s,p in enumerate(paradox[1:], start=1)]
    return paradox[-1]
    
def question_2():
    answer = zenos_paradox(0,100,5)
    print("The answer is: ", answer)

question_2()

The arrow is released at position  0
It is aimed at postion  100
Position of the arrow at step 1 is 50.0
Position of the arrow at step 2 is 75.0
Position of the arrow at step 3 is 87.5
Position of the arrow at step 4 is 93.75
Position of the arrow at step 5 is 96.875
The answer is:  96.875
```

And for 30 steps:

```
The arrow is released at position  0
It is aimed at postion  100
Position of the arrow at step 1 is 50.0
Position of the arrow at step 2 is 75.0
Position of the arrow at step 3 is 87.5
Position of the arrow at step 4 is 93.75
Position of the arrow at step 5 is 96.875
Position of the arrow at step 6 is 98.4375
Position of the arrow at step 7 is 99.21875
Position of the arrow at step 8 is 99.609375
Position of the arrow at step 9 is 99.8046875
Position of the arrow at step 10 is 99.90234375
Position of the arrow at step 11 is 99.951171875
Position of the arrow at step 12 is 99.9755859375
Position of the arrow at step 13 is 99.98779296875
Position of the arrow at step 14 is 99.993896484375
Position of the arrow at step 15 is 99.9969482421875
Position of the arrow at step 16 is 99.99847412109375
Position of the arrow at step 17 is 99.99923706054688
Position of the arrow at step 18 is 99.99961853027344
Position of the arrow at step 19 is 99.99980926513672
Position of the arrow at step 20 is 99.99990463256836
Position of the arrow at step 21 is 99.99995231628418
Position of the arrow at step 22 is 99.99997615814209
Position of the arrow at step 23 is 99.99998807907104
Position of the arrow at step 24 is 99.99999403953552
Position of the arrow at step 25 is 99.99999701976776
Position of the arrow at step 26 is 99.99999850988388
Position of the arrow at step 27 is 99.99999925494194
Position of the arrow at step 28 is 99.99999962747097
Position of the arrow at step 29 is 99.99999981373549
Position of the arrow at step 30 is 99.99999990686774
The answer is:  99.99999990686774
```